# where's the subtractive in new unreal engine 5

Tags: subtraction, box, unreal-engine5

Hy guys, does someone know where is the subtractive mode in unreal engine 5?
I'm trying to transform a simple box from additive to subtractive but it's different from Unreal engine 4.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just click on your geometry,
2. In the Detail section.
3. you can find Brush Type  By default it must be set on Additive .
   Now you can change.

Answer (score 0):

[select ue4 layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPpRE.png)

[create shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bepx.png)
[select subtract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0MHT.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).